# Why jest.spyOn does not find my component function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-component, spyon

Let's say I have this simple React (TypeScript) component:

```
function Header(): JSX.Element {
   const initialItemIndex = useInitialItemIndex();
   const [currentItem, setCurrentItem] = useState(initialItemIndex);

   function onChangeFunc(event: Event, itemNum: number): void {
       setCurrentItem(itemNum);
   }

   return (
      <div>
         <Tabs value={currentTab} onChange={onChangeFunc}>
            <Tab label="A" />
            <Tab label="B" />
         </Tabs>
      </div>
   );
}
```

I want to test (Jest, TypeScript) that the `Tabs.onChange` is calling the `onChangeFunc`. How should I test it? Something like:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Header />);
const spyFunc = jest.spyOn(Header, 'onChangeFunc');
wrapper.find('Tabs').simulate('change');
expect(spyFunc).toBeCalled();
```

I'm getting error, about the second parameter in the spyOn:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '"onChangeFunc"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1. Because it's not a property of the `Header` function, it's only defined *inside* the function. 2. It's also part of the thing you're testing, so you *shouldn't* spy on it.

Answer (score 0):

As @jonrsharpe said, the `onChangeFunc` defined inside the `Header` SFC, it's private. We can't access it so that we can't spy on it. You should test it by trigger the `change` event.

E.g.

`index.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';

export const Tabs = ({ onChange, children }) => <select onChange={onChange}>{children}</select>;
const Tab = ({ label }) => <option value={label}>{label}</option>;

export function Header(): JSX.Element {
  function onChangeFunc(event: Event, tab: number): void {
    console.log('onchange');
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Tabs onChange={onChangeFunc}>
        <Tab label="A" />
        <Tab label="B" />
      </Tabs>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```js
import { Header } from './';
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

describe('60927553', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    const wrapper = mount(<Header></Header>);
    const mEvent = {};
    wrapper.find('select').simulate('change', mEvent);
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith('onchange');
  });
});
```

unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/60927553/index.test.tsx (7.617s)
  60927553
    ✓ should pass (57ms)

  console.log node_modules/jest-environment-enzyme/node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:866
    onchange

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.86s, estimated 9s
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but this means that I'll had code just to support the tests ("console.log")?    I don't think it's good practice.

Comment: @user636312 It's just a demo. You need to assert that some methods which can be mocked or spied in the private function have to been called.

Comment: Can you, please, add example to how to mock?

Comment: @user636312 Please edit your `onChangeFunc` function, give the implementation details